# Could this be considered acceptable use of goto?

Tags: c, goto

I understand there are few places a `goto` could be useful, such as embedded for loops or cleanup for multiple function exit points. I was wondering if this could be an acceptable place to do so.

I'm building a regex engine and am using a switch statement to handle each individual character of input. Anything that is not a meta-character goes to the switch's `default`.

When I read a backslash (`\`), I want the next character to be escaped and treated literal, i.e. jump directly to the switch's `default` case. So I thought would it be okay to just `goto` to the default case by adding another label? Or should I just go the conventional way and separate it into a function?

```
for(const char* c = regex; *c; c++){
    if(*c == '\\' && *++c)
        goto literal;
    switch(*c){
        case '|':
            ...
        case '*':
            ...
            ...
        default: literal:
            ...
    }
}
```

Comment: It's difficult to know exactly what you're describing without code. If it as I think, then no, not an acceptable use of `goto`,  Just set a flag indicating the next character is escaped and continue the loop.

Comment: This question is likely off-topic due to being primarily opinion based: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: I think you meant `&& *++c` or similar.

Comment: Thank you, yes. Looking for some more clarification, I'm not sure if the down votes mean a disagreement or just not a good question.

Comment: Downvotes are probably because this question is asking for an opinion about coding style, which isn't really within the scope of the site

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's at least semi-legitimate, but you can write essentially the same code without a `goto` fairly easily:

```
for (const char* c = regex; *c; c++)
{
    switch (*c)
    {
    case '|':
        ...
    case '*':
        ...
        ...
    case '\\':
        if (*++c == '\0')
            …report backslash followed by null, probably an error…
        /*FALLTHROUGH*/
    default:
        ...
    }
}
```

Note that you'd need a `case` in your original `switch` to deal with backslash followed by EOS (`'\0'`) anyway.

Comment: I could use the `\\\` case to increment the character pointer, return if null and otherwise fall through to the default case. Looks like what I need!

Comment: Yes, you're right about the reworking...The code in my original answer wasn't quite right (it sent the code to the wrong place on `\*`, for example), and your suggestion about `case '\\':` and falling through is correct — as my revised answer suggests.  My primary conclusion (that the `goto` wasn't 100% necessary) remains accurate.